# QGIS 2.12 LAStools lasmerge error: "no outputs specified"

Tags: qgis, merge, lidar, lastools

I am trying to merge 4 .las files with "lasmerge" within "LAStools" in QGIS 2.12 running Windows 7 64. I keep on geting error "no outputs specified" even thoug i did specify the output folder and filename. LAStools is placed in C:\LAStools.

Can anyone please provide a solution to a problem?

[image: see prinscreent]

Comment: Did you update the path of the LAStools Provider (_Processing > Options... > Providers > Tools for LiDAR data_)?

Comment: Without more info this question is unclear. Besides, Joseph question how did you set the lasmerge tool arguments? If possible, show the file names and file paths, together with a data sample.